# Android Spinner creation runs event

Tags: android, loops, events, spinner

I tried to search for an answer but it's hard to find the correct terms to search for.
So my problem is that I'm creating, programmatically, a TableRow with 2 spinners with choices on it. When I choose something on that spinner it creates another row below with the same design but with diferente values on the spinners. My problem is that whenever I create the second row it is running the onItemSelect in a loop. The loop, I believe, is happening because the event is running on the new spinner that is generated. Is there a way to not have it running when I create it but only when I select the options on it?

Don't know what you require from code but I will place some here anything else just ask that I will post as soon as possible.

I create the spinner:

```
spin1 = new Spinner(this);
spin1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

On item select I add this:

```
TableRow tableRowNow = (TableRow) parent.getParent();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,            indiceSpinnerArray1);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner sItems = (Spinner) tableRowNow.getChildAt(0);
sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
sItems.setSelection(position);


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,     spinnerArray2);
                        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner sItems11 = (Spinner) tableRowNow.getChildAt(1);
sItems11.setAdapter(adapter1);
sItems11.setSelection(1);
sItems11.setEnabled(false);

newRow();

TableLayout tabLayoutTemp1 = (TableLayout) tableRowNow.getParent();
int numRowTemp = tabLayoutTemp1.indexOfChild(tableRowNow);

TableRow secondTabRow = (TableRow) tabLayoutTemp1.getChildAt(numRowTemp + 1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,     spinnerArray3);
                        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner sItems2 = (Spinner) secondTabRow.getChildAt(1);
sItems2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

And then it just keeps creating new rows to infinity .. any help ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your setSelection() calls are invoking the onItemSelect event, thus creating the infinite loop of onItemSelect invocations which also calls newRow() infinitely.

It is unclear from your code if that is the actual case, please provide the *.xml layout or at least the complete part of your Java code where you create the spinner and set the onItemSelectListener.

Comment: You were correct, I rewrote the code and found the problem was the onItemSelect being invoked on every spinner creation. Solved it by using setTag and getTag view proprieties.Thank you for your help.